# Probe permutationally matrix extreme properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose given $M\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ of rank $r$.

Assume that changing even a single $1$ to $0$ in $M$ raises rank. Does it follow that $M$ is permutationally equivalent to a block diagonal matrix with each block of rank $1$?

Assume that changing even a single $1$ to $0$ in $M$ lowers rank. Does it follow that $M$ is permutationally equivalent to a diagonal matrix?

posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171495/probe-permutationally-matrix-extreme-properties

Comment: What if $n=K^2$ and for any pair $i,j$ of numbers from 1 to $2k$ such that $i+j$ is odd there is a column $e_i+e_j$ in our matrix? It looks like rank equals $2K-1$, but becomes $2K$ after you replace 1 by 0.

Comment: Can you write this down for $K=3$ or $4$? I do not understand what your matrix is visually.

Comment: There seem to be $2K^2$ such pairs however $K^2$ columns. By pigeonhole, every pair cannot be given a column.

Comment: We need unordered pairs. Even index $i$ may be chosen by $K$ ways, odd $j$ also by $K$ ways, so totally $K^2$ (unordered) pairs.

Comment: The construction works for first question, any counter example to second question? Also did you 'guess' by standard techniques?

Comment: Please post regular answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No. Idea is to take all columns satisfying certain linear relation (i.e. lying in a certain subspace.) Then changing 1 to 0 violates this relation, and there are no immediate reasons that new relation appears. Namely, we may take, say, $n=k^2$, $k\geq 2$, and columns $e_i+e_j$ where $1\leq i\leq k$, $k+1\leq j \leq 2k$. They all satisfy a relation $x_1+\dots+x_k=x_{k+1}+\dots+x_{2k}$, and any $k^2-1$ of them generate the space generated by this relation. Thus rank equals $2k-1$, and when we change 1 to 0 columns form a space of dimension $2k$.

2) Yes for matrices over the field of characterstic 0. Consider non-zero $r\times r$ minor. Clearly there are no 1's outside it. Thus all non-zero columns are linearly independent and we have to prove that each of them is a basic vector. Assume that there are $m$ 1's in some column  (say, column $c$) and $m>1$. Let $c=\sum_{i\in I} e_i, |I|=m$. Replacing each of those 1's to 0 lowers rank, hence column $c-e_i$ is a linear combination of other columns of our matrix for any $i\in I$. Then $c=\frac1{m-1}\sum_{i\in I} (c-e_i)$ is also a linear combination of other columns. A contradiction.

On the other hand, if characteristic of the field equals $p>0$, we may consider invertible $(p+2)\times (p+2)$ matrix with 0-s on diagonal and 1-s outside diagonal. If you replace any 1 to 0 it becomes singular.

Comment: Beautiful. Think this is only counter example to $1$?

Comment: sorry is $x_i=\text{column }i$?

Comment: $x_i$ is $i$-th coordinate of a column

Comment: $i$th row essentially then?

Comment: Is this only form of counter examples?

Comment: It depends on what do you call "form".

Comment: I mean could we generate other counter examples?

Comment: Of course, many counterexamples. It looks quite a natural phenomenon that rank increases after you replace 1 to 0.

Comment: Yes exactly. We always have to have a linear relation among rows as in here?

Comment: added question in here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198937/probe-permutationally-matrix-extreme-properties-ii.

Comment: Is it possible to find a matrix along similar lines so that flipping $c$ of $1$s to $0$ would increase rank by an amount $d$?

Comment: what are $c$ and $d$?

Comment: $c,d$ are integers. Here we flip any $c=1$ of $1$s to increase rank by $d=1$. Is it possible for general $c,d$?

Comment: Sorry simple $2$ further questions. 

$\mathsf{Question}\text{ 1}:$ Assume a block diagonal $0/1$ matrix with $2$ blocks of all $1$s. The rows do not seem to satisfy any relation. Then why is rank $2$ here (I know rank is $2$) but why is there no linear relation?

$\mathsf{Question}\text{ 2}:$ Supposing maximum length linear relation we could find among rows of matrices is $r+1$, then is rank $r$?